# delphi indy udp client and server Audio chat

Tags: delphi, audio

I am creating project to make a multi audio chat through Indy components and wave audio components but I am stick with an error. It's simple code but I don't know how to fix it.

sendtocl is the client that I use

```
procedure TForm1.recorderData(Sender: TObject; const Buffer: Pointer;
  BufferSize: Cardinal; var FreeIt: Boolean);
begin
  Freeit :=True;
  sendtocl.SendBuffer(Buffer^, Buffersize);
end;
```

I got that error when compiling

> There is no overloaded version of 'SendBuffer' that can be called with these arguments

any suggested fixes ?

---

" sentocl " is my indyudpclient

```
procedure TForm1.recorderData(Sender: TObject; const Buffer: Pointer; BufferSize: Cardinal; var FreeIt: Boolean);
begin
  Freeit := True;
  sendtocl.SendBuffer(RawToBytes(Buffer^, Buffersize));
end;
```

This fixed code from Remy lebeau solve the compiling error but when i try to send the audio the text got huge data and the  other client on the network cant hear sound i think its somthing on onread with indy server the  component that i use is :

Wave audio , indy udp server and client  ,,, using delphi xe5

Remy can i send the audio stream through indyudp Client ? the sample in wave audio is for winsock but i realy lost how to do it with indy can you give me reference about that

Comment: I'm assuming you got your code from somewhere and that code was from a different version of Indy than you're using.

Comment: Yes, I have a suggestion. Look at the source code (which comes with all versions of Indy that have ever been distributed with Delphi) and figure out what the proper parameter types are for `SendBuffer`, and then fix the code so that it uses the proper types. As you've not indicated which Delphi and Indy versions you're using, and haven't even indicated what class `sentocl` is, it's impossible to be more specific. ("sendtocl is the client that I use" does not indicate the class type of that "client".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of `SendBuffer()`, it expects a `TIdBytes` as input. You can use Indy's `RawToBytes()` function for that:

```
procedure TForm1.recorderData(Sender: TObject; const Buffer: Pointer; BufferSize: Cardinal; var FreeIt: Boolean);
begin
  Freeit := True;
  sendtocl.SendBuffer(RawToBytes(Buffer^, Buffersize));
end;
```